# Resources leak con objeto Scanner

Tags: java

utilizando un objeto de tipo java.util.Scanner, eclipse me da este mensaje de advertencia:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Resource leak: 'leer' is never closed   ProbarScanner.java  /javafiles/src/com/jse/ceballos/book/tema07/guiados line 7  Java Problem

No debería el recolector de basura encargarse de estas tareas sin necesidad de llamar al método Close del objeto? Porque yo entiendo ahí que causa un problema de laguna de memoria.

Alguien puede aclararme esto?

Gracias anticipadas.

Un cordial saludo.

Answer (score -1):

A ver, **tu** debes cerrar tus recursos. El GC se ocupa de liberar la memoria que ocupan objetos no referenciados, pero no cierra nada. Cuando tu programa acabe, todos los objetos quedarían "muertos" y al final o en algún momento, si no se cierra la máquina virtual, entra el GC y limpia todo. Si la VM se cierra - pues todo desaparece al no haber proceso del sistema, el propio SO va a liberar todo. Pero en términos java tu debes cerrar los recursos que utilizas. Si no cierras un stream el GC no sabe que ya no lo utilizas. Piensa que el GC se ejecuta en tiempo de ejecución (valga la redundancia) y no ve en el futuro de código para saber si hay otra referencia de tu objeto así que no puede cerrarlo. Y simplemente GC no **cierra** nada, solo libera memoria.

Comment: Y ese voto negativo a qué se debe?